# How to read Apple developer document

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have been very confuse with how to read apple developer document. It has restrict me to learn deeper into ios coding environment beyond what Youtuber have taught me. One of the example is this

**Declaration:**

```
func run(_ configuration: ARConfiguration, 
 options: ARSession.RunOptions = [])
```

From this apple link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-run

It suppose to get me started on how to start **ARKit** but i cant understand what it wants me to do.

> - What is that line of code for?
> - How do i use that line of code?

I dont get it at all. I cant find any tutorial that explain apple documentation. Someone please explain it to me i need to know this

Comment: The documentation goes into the details of the classes and explain in finer details what each property is for. Generally, if you want to get started in a new Apple framework, watch a [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/) or read a [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/building_your_first_ar_experience)

Comment: API documentation is not a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration example just shows the parameters of the method (their types). Bellow the declaration, it is explained where that method can be used, in more detail. You asked about the purpose of the declaration; after the name of the method (the first line) it is written that it

> Starts AR processing for the session with the specified configuration and options.

So, this part answers to your first question. What's going after the example of a method declaration, answers to your second question.

Always try to read the `Discussion` section of the documentation and don't miss it. It will help you to have a basic idea what the method, property, etc. is doing.

However, there are some cases when there is almost no information is provided except a declaration. But those cases are quite rare.

Comment: i still have a hard time understanding it, could you give an example on how the code should have been placed?

Answer (score 0):

The line of code is for the following as mentioned in the documentation:

> Starts AR processing for the session with the specified configuration and options.

To answer your question of how you may use that in context we can look at the Overview for ARSession.

> Every AR experience built with ARKit requires a single ARSession object. If you use an ARSCNView or ARSKView object to easily build the visual part of your AR experience, the view object includes an ARSession instance. If you build your own renderer for AR content, you'll need to instantiate and maintain an ARSession object yourself.

If we use the first suggestion we can do the following.

```
// Create an instance of ARSKView
let view = ARSKView()

// We can get the session from the view as per documentation: 
// A view creates its own session object; use this property 
// to access and configure the view's session.
let session = view.session

// We now need to create an instance of a ARConfiguration subclass.
// Looking at the documentation we have the possibility of 
// ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, AROrientationTrackingConfiguration 
// or ARFaceTrackingConfiguration. 
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

// We can now call our function because we have all that's necessary.
// You'll notice we're not passing a value for the second parameter because it has a default parameter of an empty array.
session.run(configuration)
```

To improve on your ability of understanding documentation I recommend to identify the moment you don't have enough information for an implementation. In this case you want to call the function 
`func run(_ configuration: ARConfiguration, options: ARSession.RunOptions = [])`. Notice that that function is called on a receiver of type `ARSession` and requires an `ARConfiguration` be passed in. Your next step would be to look into those classes, specifically looking for an initializer of each and have enough of an understanding to then return to that above function and use them in it.